# Using curry to export dependencies to foreach

Tags: r, foreach, currying

I am working in R and writing an R6 class function with a foreach loop inside.  I don't want to export the R6 object into foreach - it's VERY large - but I do need to use a function that calls other functions (and I can easily export the 3-4 variables that that function needs).  Say that within my foreach I need to call a function foo:

```
foo = function(x, y) {
  z = self$goo(x)
  w = z + y
  return(w)
}
```

and then

```
foreach (...) %dopar% {
  res = foo(v1, v2)
}
```

The problem is, foo() can't run because it can't find self$goo().  I can explicitly export the whole stack but it would be easier to automatically combine dependencies of foo() into a single function.  I have tried functional::Curry, hoping that the curried function would pull in all dependent code, but to no avail.  Is there away to do with either with curry or by any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.  While functional::Curry, for instance, doesn't inject dependencies into the resulting curried function, purrr::partial does, apparently.  Also, CodeDepends is very helpful!

Comment: can you add how it would work? also you can accept your own answers, you have at least one other self-answer you can accept

Comment: Just ```purrr::partial(foo)```, and then ```foo(x, y)```